# Passing arguments to subset within a function

Tags: r

I am attempting to fit a bunch of different models to a single dataset.  Each of the models uses a different combination of outcome variable and data subset.  To fit all of these models, I created a dataframe with one column for the outcome variable and one column specifying the data subset (as a string).  (Note that the subsets are overlapping so there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to do this using nest().) I then created a new function which takes one row of this dataframe and calls "lm" using these options.  Lastly, I use pmap to map this function to the dataframe.

After a bunch of experimentation, I found an approach that works but that is rather inelegant (see below for a simplified version of what I did). It seems like there should be a way to pass the subset condition to the subset argument in lm rather than using parse(eval(text = condition)) to first create a logical vector. I read the Advanced R section on metaprogramming in the hopes that they would provide some insight, but I was unable to find anything that works.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)
outcomes <- c("mpg", "disp")
sub_conditions <- c("mtcars$cyl >=6", "mtcars$wt > 2")
models <- expand.grid(y = outcomes, condition = sub_conditions) %>% mutate_all(as.character)
fit <- function(y, condition) {
  # Create the formula to use in all models
  rx <- paste(y, "~ hp + am")
  log_vec <- eval(parse(text = condition))
  lm(rx, data = mtcars[log_vec,])
}
t <- pmap(models, fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to pass conditions in this way using string?

If that is the case, there are not many options. You can use `rlang::parse_expr` as an alternative.

```
fit <- function(y, condition) {
   rx <- paste(y, "~ hp + am")
   lm(rx, data = mtcars[eval(rlang::parse_expr(condition)),])
}
```

and call it via

```
purrr::pmap(models, fit)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak  -- Thanks for the reply.  Your code is pretty much identical to mine though. Was hoping that there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @DougJohnson yes, I was trying for the same but as I mentioned if you are passing conditions as a string like `"mtcars$cyl >=6"` there are not much options that we have.